# building a Cygwin version of GNU make

Tags: firefox, cygwin, makefile, mozilla, gnu

I want to add a couple of logging options to GNU make so I can see what is happening when building FireFox and friends.

I have the make-3.80 sources and a complete working Cygwin build environment. Starting with ./configure and the Make I get a working executable as expected.

Question: What configuration is required so the executable in an identical manner to the make.exe bundled in Moztools?

Background:

If `HAVE_CYGWIN_SHELL` is *not* defined then 
with

```
#define HAVE_CYGWIN_SHELL 1
```

Make barfs as soon as it hits this section of the Mozilla configure script

```
CWD := $(shell pwd)
ifneq (1,$(words $(CWD)))
$(error The mozilla directory cannot be located in a path with spaces.)
endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use make -n and/or make -d?  Put logging stuff into the makefile?  Modifying make itself should be an option of last resort.

Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Windows_Build_Prerequisites, it seems mozilla has moved away from cygwin.  What versions of mozilla products are you trying to build?

(Note that Visual C can be downloaded for free; look for the "Express Edition".)

Comment: The debug options don't really help as they are too verbose. Adding logging to the makefiles is virtually impossible as they are (literally) hundreds of them & they need to track new releases. Even modifying the configure scripts to 'echo' all command fails for some cases. The build system is incredibly fragile - the configure scripts (3 of them) are ~23K lines each. 

But your answer points spotlights the obvious point I missed - it may be the mingw-msys source I need, not the GNU code. 

Thx++