# Is there a Cygwin version of GNU make?

Tags: cygwin, gnu-make

Android's NDK requires **both** [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) *and* [GNU Make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Since I already have the latest & greatest Cygwin installed, I thought that GNU Make must have already been included in it, as Cygwin is pretty developer-oriented.

But I couldn't find any, neither in my local installation, nor in the list of packages, which makes me very curious to understand why, of all GNU packages, this is the one Cygwin chose not to include.

Or perhaps such [Cygwin version of GNU make](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085018) exists and I just couldn't find it?

If so, where/how do I download it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `make` package is GNU make

[`cygwin.com/packages/make`](http://cygwin.com/packages/make)

```
The GNU version of the 'make' utility
```

Be sure to install from the **Internet**, not from "Local Directory":

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I added a screenshot that explains why I couldn't initially find it: I did type `make` in the search box. It wasn't there. It was only after this tip that I realized I am attempting to install from a package that is not **cached** locally in PC. +1 and accepting.